# Run bat file as administator != CMD as admin & execute line by line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, batch-file

I hope someone can help with this issue. SO Win10 x64.

I need to copy one XPI file (Firefox extension) to a Program Files (not x86) subfolder. If I do a simple bat file, and run it as administrator with right-click, mkdir works ok but the copy operation doesn't work. Instead, if I open cmd as admin and run the copy operation from there, both mkdir and copy operation works as expected.

I'm need to call the BAT from a third-party software with elevated privileges, so if I can solve the first scenario, I should be able to solve my problem. Any help or explanation is much appreciated. Code is very simple:

```
mkdir "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\distribution\extensions"
copy file.xpi "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\distribution\extensions"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using xcopy instead of copy.

Alternatively have you thought about using powershell?

It is much more powerfull and you can specify credentials for a [process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6). 
You can also Bypass the execution policy with Powershell.

```
Set-Executionpolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force
```

Then you can copy the program in powershell using

```
xcopy /q <source> <destination>
```

If that doesn't work try putting the xcopy command in a Start-Process powershell command.
Something like...

```
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe" -ArgumentList "file.xpi  C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\distribution\extensions\" -Credential domain\user
```

Alternatively domain\user would be computername\user

Note that Start-Process also has the -Wait switch, which waits for the process to finish.

Comment: After a lot of learning about Powershell and testing, I was able to achieve what I want but only with a registry hack (running the BAT file as administrator): 

`REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
TIMEOUT 3
xcopy 'FULLPATHTOFILE.EXT' "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\distribution\extensions\"
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin /t REG_DWORD /d 5 /f`

It disables UAC for a couple of seconds, it isn't the best solution

Comment: Previous attemp was:
`powershell -command "   Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs \""-Command 
`\""cd '%cd%'; & '.\xcopy.ps1';`\""\""   "`

xcopy.ps1 content:
`Start-Process xcopy -ArgumentList "file.xpi `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\distribution\extensions\`"" -Verb runAs`

Which It works only if I call the first batch without privileges, and it prompts UAC warning on Powershell.

I'll try to migrate my application to use entirely Powershell.

Comment: Remember to Set-Execution policy in your script, and have you tried the Start-Process with the -Credential argument? 
That should allow you to run the copy process with any user on your domain.

PowerShell also has this ability. 

    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Administrator", $password)